# Parametric graph

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I am new to Mathematica. I need to graph a parametric equation.  The problem says to graph the following parametrically: `x=Cos[t]^2  y=Sin[t]^2 z=t`

 I tried:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t]^2}, {Sin[t]^2}, {t}, {t, -3, 3}]
```

I keep receiving an error message that says options (a rule or list of rules) are expected instead of`{t,-3,3}`. What are the options/rules that I should exchange the limits for?

Comment: The components should be in a single list, before the iterator: `{Cos[t]^2, Sin[t]^2, t}`. Try it with this again.

Comment: Like this: ParametricPlot3D[{t, -3, 3}, {Cos[t]^2}, {Sin[t]^2}, {t}] ?

Comment: Look carefully. There is a difference between `{Cos[t]^2, Sin[t]^2, t}` and `{Cos[t]^2}, {Sin[t]^2}, {t}`. You are typing too many things. Also, the iterator comes after the list of components.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Oh, okay. What is an iterator?

Comment: Good news! I figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Help-Function (F1 *key*), in particular [ParametricPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t]^2, Sin[t]^2, t}, {t, -5, 5}]
```

[image]